# Error output (Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException)

Tags: python

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException
================ Error Output: ================
 line 15 if loaded_model.predict(X)[0][0] &gt;= 0.5: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The original code is if loaded_model.predict(X)[0][0] >= 0.5:

After change the code to >=, the another error shows,

```
Code: 1(General error),Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Traceback (most recent call last)
line 1, in <module> from keras.models import load_model File
line 1, in <module> from keras.models import load_model ImportError: No module named models
```

Please help

```
#keras.py
from keras.models import load_model
from cv2 import imread, resize
from numpy import zeros

# Path of the Image To Test
img_path = "wound.jpg"
loaded_model = load_model('./content/wound_classification')

# Load and preprocess Image
X = zeros((1, 300, 300, 3))
X[0] = resize(imread(img_path), (300, 300))
X[0] = X[0] / 255.0

# Predict Image
if loaded_model.predict(X)[0][0] >= 0.5:
    print("Wound is Non Chronic")
else:
    print("Wound is Chronic")
```

The code works well in my computer but after upload to plesk control panel. It doest works, does anyone have this problem and solution?
or need to install keras in plesk control panel? and how to install because google didn't shows the way to install keras in plesk control panel.

Comment: How did you upload it?  If someone changed the `>` to `&gt;`, then you have to change it back.

Comment: After change it back to >= , another error shows,=============== Error Output: ================ Traceback (most recent call last): File line 1, in <module> from keras.models import load_model File

Comment: Please edit your question.  It's too hard to read long error tracebacks in comments.

Comment: Done amend tim. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible you created your own file called "keras.py"?

Comment: Actually i had create a file name keras.py and had import the library. I can use it offline but once upload to plesk platform, the file cannot read as offline does.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install keras using pip (e.g. `pip install keras` or `pip install <zip file>` from the releases https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases)

you don't have the right keras package installed. that's why your code does not work.

also, rename your `keras.py` file to be something else as your are confusing python imports

Comment: it works in my computer but after upload to plesk control panel, it doesn't work.

Comment: have you installed keras on the target machine?as far as I know, plesk is just a frontend for the servers itself. you have to install all the packages on the server anyway (I never used plesk)

Comment: as far as I see, you have "Command Line Interface" (Perform operations on Plesk objects from the command line). you should use this to run pip install on the remote machine